# Tree structure with parents and children

Tags: c#, parent-child, friend, tree-structure

I'm trying to make a tree structure of parents and children. The problem is that I only want to be able to assign the parent of a child in the child and parent classes, and nowhere else:

```
public class Parent
{
    public static Parent Root = new Parent();
    
    private List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Child> Children
    {
        get { return children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AppendChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Parent.RemoveChild(child);
        child.children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this; //I need to asign the childs parent in some way
    }
    public void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        if (this.children.Remove(child))
        {
            child.Parent = Parent.Root; //here also
        }
    }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    private Parent parent = Parent.Root;
    public Parent Parent
    {
        get { return this.parent; }
        private set { this.parent = value; } //nothing may change the parent except for the Child and Parent classes
    }
}
```

By a not-C# programmer, I was told to use friends (like in C++), but those aren't implemented in C#, and all my other solutions failed.

Comment: Try to use protected.

Comment: How is that going to help?

Comment: Protected is one of the things that I already tried, but I can't use a protected field of an other instance of the parent than itself in the child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not answer your question but it is an alternative. This is a node structure and you could use something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    private Node _parent;
    private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();

    public Node(Node parent)
    {
        _parent = parent
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Node> Children
    {
        get { return _children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AppendChild(Node child)
    {
        // your code
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Node child)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

I see @zmbq has just edited to suggest something similar.

Comment: You all suggested this solution, so it was hard to choose wich one to accept, but I want to thank you all for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you can also be responsible for actually creating the children and parents (you can provide factory methods for this), you can use interfaces and private classes to achieve this.

```
interface IChild
{
    // methods and properties for child, including
    IParent Parent { get; } // No setter.
}

interface IParent
{
   // Methods and properties for parent
}
```

Now, you create a *private* implementation of `IChild` that also has a Parent setter. In your code call your private implementation, but only return `IChild` and `IParent`.

Note - private classes are nested classes in C#. I can't tell you in which class these classes should be nested - that depends on your project. If there's no such reasonable place you can create a child/parent DLL library, and have `internal` Child and Parent classes that implement the public interfaces.

Incidentally, I don't understand why you have both `Parent` and `Child` classes, and especially not why Child is derived from Parent. If you have one `Node` class, you can have a `Parent` property with a private setter, and not worry about it.

Comment: The problem with a 'node' would be that there is no root with only children, that's why I created a parent object for this. But should I have a Node class, how would I implement a root?

Comment: Your root would simply have a parent set to null. If it's important for your class or consuming code, maybe expose an IsRoot() method on your node which checks if it has a parent and returns a boolean.

Comment: What @JoelGregory said. That's how tree nodes are usually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If you require `Parent` and `Child` to be different classes, then you can do this using events.  Make the `Parent` class offer an event whenever a `Child` is added and removed, then make the `Child` listen for this and sets its own parent appropriately.  Effectively the child list in the `Parent` becomes the primary data and the parent becomes a back reference, like so:

```
public class ParentChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public ParentChangedEventArgs(Parent parent, Child child)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.Child = child;
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public static event EventHandler<ParentChangedEventArgs> ParentChanged; // Could be internal or protected.

    public static Parent Root = new Parent(); // SHOULDN'T THIS BE READONLY?

    private readonly List<Child> children = new List<Child>();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Child> Children
    {
        get { return children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AppendChild(Child child)
    {
        var oldParent = child.Parent;
        if (oldParent == this)
            return;
        oldParent.children.Remove(child);
        this.children.Add(child);
        if (ParentChanged != null)
            ParentChanged(oldParent, new ParentChangedEventArgs(this, child));
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Child child)
    {
        Root.AppendChild(child); // Removing a child means adding it to the root.
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    static Child()
    {
        Parent.ParentChanged += new EventHandler<ParentChangedEventArgs>(Parent_ChildChanged);
    }

    static void Parent_ChildChanged(object sender, ParentChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var child = e.Child;
        child.Parent = e.Parent;
    }

    private Parent parent = Parent.Root;

    public Parent Parent
    {
        get { return this.parent; }
        private set { this.parent = value; }
    }
}
```

(Of course, if they were the same class, then everything could be private and this mechanism would not be necessary.)